# How to reorder the rows and columns of a matrix multiplying a vector indexed by (i,j)

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

I am trying to construct a particular matrix `A` which multiplies a column vector `v= [p_0,0; p_0,1; ... p_0,N; p_1,0; ...; p_N,N]`.

I know the required matrix (`B` say) if the vector v was rearranged in the order given by sorting by the second index before the first  ( i.e if `v` were `[p_0,0; p_1,0; ... p_N,0; p_0,1; ...; p_N,N]`), however would like to rearrange the rows and columns of this matrix to obtain `A` so that it multiplies the correctly ordered v.

Example:

```
B = 
   -2.6667    1.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   -0.5000         0    0.5000         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -1.0000   -0.4706         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0   -2.6667    1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0   -0.5000         0    0.5000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0   -1.0000   -0.4706         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0   -2.6667    1.0000         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0   -0.5000         0    0.5000
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0   -1.0000   -0.4706
```

multiplying v in the wrong order

```
p_0,0
p_1,0 
p_2,0
p_0,1
p_1,1
p_2,1
p_0,2
p_1,2
p_2,2
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're asking. I can't make heads or tails from your question, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. `B` I supposed to be a matrix? Please format it accordingly. And you want to reorder columns of `B`?

Comment: Hi Cris, sorry that it is not clear. I am not sure how to format it as a matrix - I am new to the site. I want to reorder the rows and columns of `B` so that each row multiplied by `v` gives the same result as the corresponding product in `A*v`. For example the first row in the above example gives `-2.6667*p_0,0, +1.0000*p_1,0 . `. When `v` is in the correct order, the 1.0000 would need to be in the 4th column to still multiply p_1,0. Hence the second column must move to the 4th column. (Similarly for the next line, the 3rd column must move to the seventh for  0.5000 to multiply p_2,0).

Comment: Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understood, you want to convert matrix `B` to the matrix `A` in the following order:

`v1= [p_0,0; p_0,1; ... p_0,N; p_1,0; ...; p_N,N]`

`v2=[p_0,0; p_1,0; ... p_N,0; p_0,1; ...; p_N,N]`

where `A*v1` equals to `B*v2`.

For this, you need **swapping** of each row of the matrix.

Try this code:

```
m=length(B);   % m is equal to NxN
N=sqrt(m);
A=zeros(m,m);
for i=0:N-1
    for j=0:N-1
        A(j+i*N+1,:)=B(i+N*j+1,:);
    end
end
```